# How to let users delete their account from the frontend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, user

How can i let my registered users delete their own account from the front-end?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at this extension called **Delete My Account**:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/user-management/26011

It allows users to delete their own account via the frontend. There is also a feature where it notifies all admins if a user has deleted their account. Looks like a promising extension and exactly what you need. Compatible with Joomla 2.5 and 3.x

**Update:**

I have just tested this plugin on my localhost and it works perfectly fine.

1. Install the plugin
2. Enable it and in the options, set **Action to be taken** to **delete**
3. You then need to place a link with with a specific class. You can place this link literally anywhere you want. I decided to put it in an article, simply to test. So add the following somewhere on your site: `<a href="#" class="f90-delete-my-account">Delete my account</a>`
4. When you click on this link in the frontend, it should load a modal box asking you to confirm that you want to delete your account.

Comment: I downloaded but it didn't worked? or May be i couldn't understand the documentations. I checked the site, alot of users are complaining about the plugin but many of them also appreciating the product? can you help me with the documentation?

Comment: @Saibbyweb - see my updated answer

Comment: it doesn't work? Nothing shows up!

Comment: Do you mean the link or the modal box?

Comment: when i click on the link, nothing happens!

Comment: And in the plugin parameters, do you have jQuery set to yes or no? Which ever option it is currently set to, change to the opposite

Comment: i set jQuery & Bootstrap to NO! & it worked! :)

Answer (score 3):

Community Builder Profile Privacy plugin also does this, if you use Community Builder for your membership management.

Besides deleting an account, it also allows user to temporarily disable their account on front-end, so it's not active but keeps the data to reactivate later.  And it includes options for administrators to allow front-end privacy controls on a field-by-field basis (e.g. force showing name & city, but allow hiding street & phone number).

To set up, install Community Builder, then add CB Privacy from the Community Builder plugin management.  Make sure it's enabled, which will automatically add the disable & delete options to the bottom of the user profile.

To add privacy to specific fields, select the field, find the Privacy tab in "Integrations" section of the field editing and select the options you prefer.  To leave it out for any field choose "Normal CB Settings".  You can also used "Forced privacy control" to make sure a field stays private that you don't want users publishing by accident.

More info here: https://www.joomlapolis.com/addons/cb-privacy (Requires active membership to download)